# Need a new command that modifies the uppercase letters in its argument

Tags: math-mode, macros

I was trying to write a new command for expected value operator, such that if its argument is a uppercase letter then it will replace it with a `\mathrm` one, e.g. from `E(X)` to `E(\mathrm{X})`; and will expand lowercase letter as is. For a single letter, I can simply do the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\E}[1]{\mathrm{E}
\lparen
\ifnum `#1=\uccode`#1
\mathrm{#1}
\else #1
\fi
\rparen}

\begin{document}

\[\E{X}\]

\end{document}
```

However, if the input is a series of characters, say `e^{tX}`, this methods will blunder. I'd like to know if there is a method to check the "uppercaseness" of an argument and modify it accordingly.

**Remark**:
This command is only for notation of random variables, so I still want uppercase letter italic elsewhere.

Comment: It seems to me that you'd like to have French style, where uppercase letters in math are upright. Doing it that way is surely the wrong thing to try.

Comment: @egreg: This command is only for notation of random variables, so I still want uppercase letter italic elsewhere.

Comment: The best method is to define a command, say `\newcommand{\rd}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}` and use it.

Comment: so `\E(aBc)` will leave `a` and `c` slanted and make `B` upright? then you could use a method based on a math alphabet (but lowercase and uppercase would need two symbol fonts for simplicity; or, one may change the family bit on the fly using mathcode's.) Or `\E` could make the uppercase letters mathematically active and have them expand to what is needed.

Comment: @egreg: tried that before, however when the document gets lengthy proofreading becomes difficult :P that's why I am trying to set up a command that will do it automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\change@uppercase@math}{%
  \count@=`\A
  \loop
    \mathcode\count@\count@
    \ifnum\count@<`\Z
    \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat}

\newcommand{\E}[1]{
  \mathrm{E}
  (\begingroup\change@uppercase@math#1\endgroup)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\E{X}+\E{e^{tX}}$
\end{document}
```

Slow, of course. I stick with my opinion that it's better to mark what you want upright.

[image]

Comment: This is clever, it works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want all uppercase roman you can do something like this (or you can do it locally if that is needed)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\count@`A
\loop
\mathcode\count@\count@
\ifnum\count@<`Z
\advance\count@\@ne
\repeat
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$abc+ABC+def+DEF+ghijklmnop+GHIJKLMNOP$

$qQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah shame you clarified in comments that you don't want it globally, shame:-)

Comment: sorry about the unclarity, will change the question :P

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested, but the following (incompatible with unicode engines) should be compatible with arbitrary math font contexts. In particular it does not assume that the `\mathrm` alphabet will choose the math family `0`. The command `\E`, before issueing `\mathrm` on its arguments, first makes, in a group, all lowercase letters unresponsive to math alphabets. Package `xint` is used for easier computing (expandably).

```
\documentclass{article}
% not compatible with unicode engines

\usepackage{xint} 

\makeatletter

% this macro will make the lowercase letter unresponsive to
% math changing alphabets; and this is compatible to arbitrary
% math font setup.

%
\def\@makeunreactive #1{%
    \mathcode`#1=\xintRem{\the\mathcode`#1}{4096}
}

\newcommand*\E[1]{%
  \begingroup
     \@tfor\x:=\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z\do
     {\expandafter\@makeunreactive\x}% 
     \mathrm{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


$\E{abcdefghijklmnopqrestuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRESTUVWXYZ}$

\end{document}
```

[image: uppercase upright]

Comment: there is a spurious `e` (in uppercase too) in the image... but fortunately it is also in the source, so ok.